# Endomorphisms in an exact sequence of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let X be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. And suppose we have an exact sequence of vector bundles over $X$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow 0$.

Suppose $C$ is simple, i.e. $End(C)=\mathbb{C}$, is $A$ simple too?

My argument is as follows. Since $A$ is a subsheaf of $B$, $End(A)\subset End(B)$. Choose $\phi\in End(A) \subset End{B}$. So $\phi$ is a morphism from $B\longrightarrow B$, such that $\phi(A)\subset A$. Hence it induces a morphism $C\longrightarrow C$. Hence $\phi\in\mathbb{C}$.

Is this argument correct? The step where I have a doubt is that $End{A}\subset End{B}$. Any feedback will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The statement about containment $End$ is not true. $End$ is not a functor and there's no reason a map $A \to A$ should extend to a map $B \to A$ (or $B \to B$).

Comment: Ah thank you @JakeLevinson! Can you give me an example when this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample. Let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$. Take $C = \mathcal{O}(2)$, which has three global sections, i.e. there is a surjective map $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3} \to \mathcal{O}(2)$, which is an isomorphism on global sections. Let $K$ be the kernel, a rank-2 vector bundle.

Since every vector bundle on on $\mathbb{P}^1$ splits as a sum of line bundles, $K = \mathcal{O}(a) \oplus \mathcal{O}(b)$. The Chern class of $K$ must satisfy

$$c(K) = (1+a[pt])(1+b[pt]) = \frac{1}{1+2[pt]} = 1 - 2[pt],$$

so $a + b = -2$. On the other hand, $K$ has no global sections, by construction, so $a,b\leq -1$. So $a = b = -1$ (incidentally, it's probably easy to see this directly, I'm just being lazy), and so $End(K) = \mathbb{C}^4$.

Moreover, in this example, $Hom(B,A) = Hom(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3},\mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus2}) = 0$.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe we can just say that degree is additive in short exact sequences of vector bundles. So $deg(K)+deg(\mathcal{O}(2))=deg(\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3})$. Hence, $a+b+2=0$.

Comment: Sorry @JakeLevinson, $End(\mathcal{O}^3)=M_3=\mathbb{C}^9$ right? Then $End(A)$ is indeed contained in $End(B)$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The fact that $End(\mathcal{O}^3) = \mathbb{C}^9$ and $End(K) = \mathbb{C}^4$ does not imply anything by itself -- a priori these are just two totally unrelated vector spaces. You would need to actually describe how $End(A)$ embeds in $End(B)$, and in general there is no such rule.

Comment: @poorna: Continuing with the ideas in the counterexample above, construct a short exact sequence $0 \to K = \mathcal{O}(a) + \mathcal{O}(b) \to \mathcal{O}^3 \to \mathcal{O}(n) \to 0$ by sending the three sections to $x^n, x^{n-1}y,y^n$ respectively. Then show $a+b+n = 0$ by counting degrees, and then show $H^1(K(n-3)) = \mathbb{C}$, which implies $\{a,b\} = \{1-n,-1\}$. Now for large $n$, $End(K) = \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, which is way bigger than $End(\mathcal{O}^3) = \mathbb{C}^9$.

Comment: @poorna: The underlying issue with endomorphisms of vector bundles is that our inclusion $A \to B$ is not sufficient data to *naturally* convert an endomorphism $A \to A$ into an endomorphism $B \to B$, or vice versa. In other words, it does not induce any natural map $End(A) \to End(B)$ or vice versa. On the other hand, a *pair* of maps $A \to B$, $B \to A$ determines a pair(!) of maps $End(A) \to End(B)$ and $End(B) \to End(A)$. But, as in the above, there need not be *any* maps $B \to A$, let alone "good enough" maps to yield nice comparisons between $End(A)$ and $End(B)$.

Comment: Ah thanks so much! I wish I could upvote your answer again! It is very clear now. @Jake Levinson

Comment: @poorna: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 3):

If $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact, so is $0\to A\oplus A\to B\oplus A\to C\to 0$, where the second copy of $A$ maps as identity to the same factor in the middle. Surely, $A\oplus A$ is not simple.